# want to create a list of countdown timers using javascript based on an example of a single countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a list of countdowns like

"Countdown to the Independence Day   A days B hours C minutes
Countdown to X mas X days Y hours Z minutes"

I now understand how to create a single countdown timer using https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

But I want to create a list of multiple countdown timers. I will appreciate your comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+multiple+timers+same+page+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also w3schools is not a great resource. They have improved but there are still questionable code and recommendations on that site. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is where I go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question, and even if you rephrased it to something like "how do I create a list of countdown timers?" you should provide more details such as "here's what I've tried", or "here's where I'm confused", etc. so that we can provide an answer that actually helps you learn or solve a problem rather than just throwing code at you.

Here's a simple solution based on the W3schools code:

```js
// Set the dates we're counting down to
var countDownDate1 = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();
var countDownDate2 = new Date("July 7, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Countdown and display time remaining
function countDown(time, elm) {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the time parameter
  var distance = time - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element we got from the parameter elm
  elm.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    console.log(elm);
    elm.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}

// Get elements
var demo1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
var demo2 = document.getElementById("demo2");

// Update the count downs every 1 second
setInterval(() => countDown(countDownDate1, demo1), 1000);
setInterval(() => countDown(countDownDate2, demo2), 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function setCountDown(countDownFor, date){
  // Get CountDown Date and Time
  const countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
  // Current Date and Time
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  // Get the Distance between them
  const distance = countDownDate - now;
  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  // Create new Div
  const node = document.createElement("DIV");
  // Set the Date Time for the Countdown
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(countDownFor +" := "+days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
  // Add Countdown Text to Div Element
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  // Add div to our main Demo Div
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);

  // Start Countdown Timer using Set Interval. It will Trigger at every second
  setInterval(function() {   
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const distance = countDownDate - now;
    const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    node.innerHTML = countDownFor +" := "+days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  }, 1000);
}
setCountDown("Christmas","Dec 25, 2021")
setCountDown("Independent Day","Aug 15, 2021")
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function setCountDown(countDownFor, date){
  // Get CountDown Date and Time
  const countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
  // Current Date and Time
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  // Get the Distance between them
  const distance = countDownDate - now;
  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  // Create new Div
  var node = document.createElement("DIV");
  // Set the Date Time for the Countdown
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(countDownFor +" := "+days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
  // Add Countdown Text to Div Element
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  // Add div to our main Demo Div
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);

  // Start Countdown Timer using Set Interval. It will Trigger at every second
  setInterval(function() {   
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const distance = countDownDate - now;
    const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    node.innerHTML = countDownFor +" := "+days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  }, 1000);
}
setCountDown("Christmas","Dec 25, 2021")
setCountDown("Independent Day","Aug 15, 2021")
</script>

</body>
</html>
```